# Passing lambda to an object and modify that object from inside the lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, capture

I have code that looks like this:

```
struct LambdaContainer{ 
    std::function<void(void)> f;
    float x = 10;
}

struct MyClass{
    LambdaContainer c;

}
void someFunction(){
    MyClass ins;
    LambdaContainer cont;
    cont.f = [&cont](){
        // I want to modify 'x' of LambdaContainer that is inside MyClass

        cont.x = 10; // won't work because cont will be copy constructed
                     // and this cont might not exist anymore
    };
    ins.c = cont;
    aVectorSomewhere.push_back(ins);
}
```

Is there any way I can capture the LambdaContainer 'cont' in such a way that it's referring to wherever the lambda is called from? (I'm not using pointer, by the way)

Thank you for such great answers :) I think I can get it to work now

Comment: It seems to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the *actual* problem? You might have a simple solution to the actual problem once you state it.

Comment: I'm making a game where each enemy has unique routes. I don't want to subclass my enemy script for every object I have so I'm trying to make it functional, and code the routes in my initialization code. So what I'm planning to do is pass a bunch of lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of capturing `cont`, pass it to the stored lambda:

```
class LambdaContainer
{ 
private:
    std::function<void(LambdaContainer&)> f;

public:
    float x = 10;

    void call_f()
    {
        f(*this);
    }
};

void someFunction()
{
    MyClass ins;
    LambdaContainer cont;
    cont.f = [](LambdaContainer& self)
    {    
        self.x = 10;
    };

    ins.c = cont;
    aVectorSomewhere.push_back(ins);
}
```

When you want to invoke the lambda, simply execute `LambdaContainer::call_f` from an existing instance or add a way to call `call_f` from `MyClass` depending on your design.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't copy or assign things unnecessarily, and it will be OK (not to mention more efficient):

```
struct LambdaContainer { 
    std::function<void(void)> f;
    float x = 10;
};   
struct MyClass {
    LambdaContainer c;
    MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete; // noncopyable
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = delete;
};
void someFunction(){
    MyClass ins;
    ins.c.f = [&ins](){
        ins.c.x = 10;
    };
    aVectorSomewhere.emplace_back(std::move(ins));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `ins` to be dynamically allocated and store the `MyClass*` pointer in your vector (using `std::unique_ptr`).  This way, the address that the lambda captures does not change during the object's lifetime, as there is no copying involved.

```
struct LambdaContainer {
    std::function<void(void)> f;
    float x = 10;
};

struct MyClass {
    LambdaContainer c;
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> aVectorSomewhere;

void someFunction() {
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ins(new MyClass);
    LambdaContainer &cont = ins->c;
    cont.f = [cont]() {
        cont.x = 10;
    };
    aVectorSomewhere.push_back(std::move(ins));
}
```

Then, to call the lambda later:

```
aVectorSomewhere[index]->c.f();
```